# Excel: Get sum if value of another column is non-blank?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I think this is really simple and a duplicate. However, much Googling hasn't helped me find the answer. So I thought I'd ask a nice clear StackExchange question, to help people using the same search terms as me.

I have an Excel spreadsheet like this:

```
country,population_in_m,in_world_cup
uk,64,y
france,66,y
germany,80,y
poland,38,
```

How do I get the sum of entries in the B column for all rows with non-blank values in the C column?

Right now I have this:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B5,"<>",C2:C5)
```

based on lots of Googling, but that just gives me a VALUE error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you have the ranges reversed.  The evaluation range is first and the sum range is last.  It should be:

```
=SUMIF(C2:C5,"<>",B2:B5)
```